# Ruby/CMD: When does ruby stop 'using' a file?

Tags: ruby, cmd

I am writing a code that uses a mix of both ruby and batch programming (Indeed, I know that that isn't exactly the brightest idea, but I have much more experience with cmd, and sadly I was tasked to solve this problem with ruby.)

I am facing a strange issue whereby on the first run of the ruby file (clean, with no other external files created), I face the error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Yet, on subsequent runs (with the database file already in place in the same directory as the .rb file), I do not get the same error and the program runs flawlessly.

Here is a sample of the code I am running:

```
if someCondition
  File.open('database.csv','a+') { |f|
    f.puts ic.to_s + "," + tix.to_s
  }
else # if the database does contain
  system 'RENAME database.csv tempin.txt'
  write_handler = File.new("TEMPORARY.txt", "w") 
  write_handler.puts(ic).to_s
  write_handler.close

  write_handler = File.new("temp.bat","w")
  write_handler.puts('@ECHO off
                      SET /P MYVAR=<TEMPORARY.txt
                      findstr /v "%MYVAR%" tempin.txt > tempout.txt
                      ERASE tempin.txt
                      RENAME tempout.txt database.csv')
  write_handler.close

  system 'temp.bat
          ERASE temp.bat'
end
```

In short it takes the ruby string 'ic', writes it to a txt file, which is then read by cmd to the variable MYVAR. Then, using findstr, it deletes all lines containing %MYVAR%, before writing to an output file. (I do this to ensure there are no duplicate entries in the database.)

I suspect that the..

```
File.open('database.csv','a+') {...
```

..is what is causing the "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process", as perhaps this means ruby is currently 'using' the database file, causing cmd to be unable to 'use' it.

Yet, this doesn't explain why on subsequent runs (where the database.csv is already in place), I do not face an error and the entire file runs smoothly.

I suspect this has to do with the read/write permissions I am using (As a side note, I am using a+ because I want to append, not replace data in my csv file.)

I would greatly appreciate if someone could enlighten me on what is wrong, and why it is that on a clean run it fails but on a subsequent run it does not.

Comment: The block form of `File.open` you are using closes the file at the "}"